# Read specific sheets and append files in Python

Tags: python

I have multiple xlsx files in a folder. I need to check for sheet name "vinf". If this exist, then keep appending it into new file in python.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out by my own.

```
path = r'C:/MY_FOLDER/WPP/December work/AM WPP ACCESS SOURCES/03-Cluster 3 OPCOs  RVtool Reports - NEW/Y&R/Dec 2017' # use your path
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_excel(file_,sheetname = 'vinf')
    list_.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(list_)

frame.to_excel('C:/MY_FOLDER/WPP/December work/AM WPP ACCESS SOURCES/03-Cluster 3 OPCOs  RVtool Reports - NEW/Y&R/FINAL_OM_XLSX.xlsx',index = False)
```

Thanks